# LEFT Join not returning records in MS Access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, left-join

My recent project I have a requirements to print receivable summary. I need to return entire rows from the `OpeningBalance` table and matching rows from `VoucherHeader` and `Customers`.

My SQL query is this

```
SELECT 
    OpeningBalance.OpenID, Sum(OpeningBalance.Amount) AS SumOfAmount,  
    Sum(VoucherHeader.Debit) AS SumOfDebit, Sum(VoucherHeader.Credit) AS SumOfCredit, 
    Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CustomerName 
FROM 
   (OpeningBalance 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   VoucherHeader ON OpeningBalance.OpenID = VoucherHeader.LedgerID) 
INNER JOIN 
   Customers ON OpeningBalance.OpenID = Customers.CustomerID
WHERE 
   (((Customers.CustomerType)='Debtor') 
     AND ((VoucherHeader.VoucherDate)<#2013/06/02#))
GROUP BY 
    OpeningBalance.OpenID, Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CustomerName, 
    VoucherHeader.LedgerID
ORDER BY 
    Customers.CustomerName;
```

Please help.

Comment: What's the question? Please describe what you would like to achieve and how those tables are related to each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OB.OpenID, Sum(OB.Amount) AS SumOfAmount,  
Sum(VB.Debit) AS SumOfDebit, Sum(VB.Credit) AS SumOfCredit, CS.CustomerID,
CS.CustomerName FROM OpeningBalance OB 
LEFT OUTER JOIN VoucherHeader VB ON OB.OpenID = VB.LedgerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers CS ON OB.OpenID =   CS.CustomerID
WHERE (((CS.CustomerType)='Debtor') AND ((VB.VoucherDate)<#2013/06/02#))
GROUP BY OB.OpenID, CS.CustomerID, CS.CustomerName, VB.LedgerID
ORDER BY CS.CustomerName;
```